# USING TRIGGERS Write a query to bring ACCOUNT record which has more than 100 CONTACTS

Tags: apex, trigger

Write a query to bring ACCOUNT record which has more than 100 CONTACTS?HERE ACCOUNTS AND CONTACTS ARE STANDARD OBJECTS

Comment: What is your question? What code have you written thus far? More information would help us better assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, it seems that you need list of all the Accounts that are having more than 100 Contacts.
So the solution here is to use [SOQL Aggregate Result](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_query_aggregateresult.htm) query which would query the child (Contacts) and group by the parent (Account Id) lookup.

---

**So the required query is** :

---

```
List<AggregateResult> ar = [
 Select Count(Id) numRecs,Account.id
 From Contact
 Group By Account.id 
 Having Count(Id) > 100     
];
```